# Fazer update dentro de uma função mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, funções, sql-update

Tenho que fazer um processo para realizar um update em um determinado campo de uma tabela.

criei uma função no mysql. Porém dentro desta função precisaria realizar um update, mais a função não aceita uptade teria alguma forma de realizar este procedimento?

O erro que aparece é o seguinte:

> Cant update table T043 in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Segue a função que criei

```
CREATE DEFINER=`hardness`@`%` FUNCTION `T059_PAC_Fornecedor_Multiplo`(
xT043_Id int(11),
xT043_Qtd int(11),
xT059_T010_Id int(11)) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN    
   DECLARE xPacQtd INT DEFAULT 0;  
   DECLARE xCount INT DEFAULT 0; 
   DECLARE xCountResult INT DEFAULT 0; 
   SET xPacQtd = T059_PAC_Fornecedor(xT043_Id, xT059_T010_Id);

   IF ((xT043_Qtd % xPacQtd) = 0) THEN
       return xT043_Qtd;
   END IF;

   sloop:LOOP
     SET xCount=xCount+1;
     SET xCountResult = (xPacQtd*xCount);

     IF xCountResult > xT043_Qtd THEN
        UPDATE T043 SET T043_QUANTIDADE = xCountResult WHERE T043_Id = xT043_Id;
        LEAVE sloop;
     END IF;
   END LOOP sloop;

   RETURN xCountResult;
END
```

Comment: Bom dia, esta dando algum erro?